# how to upper string characters at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to take astring and indeses on that string and to convert these characters on those indexes to upper.
this is what I've tried but it doesn't work. it shows
"list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

```
test = 'hello there'
l = list(test)
def capital(s, ind):
    for i in s:
        i = list(i)
        i[ind] = i[ind].upper()
    print(s)
capital(l,[1,2,5])
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: change the indices in the string to uppercase letters

Comment: It would be better if you join the list into a string once you are done capitalizing the letters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People are overcomplicating this in their answers. You shouldn't need to iterate over the string, if you already have a defined list of indexes to capitalize. Here's what you can do, iterating only over the indexes parameter:

```python
def capital(text, indexes):
  split_text = list(text)
  for i in indexes:
    split_text[i] = split_text[i].upper()
  return ''.join(split_text)

capitalized = capital('hello there', [1, 2, 5])
print(capitalized)
```

This would print `hELlo there`.

A shorter alternative would be using the function [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), since you're working with both values and indexes of a sequence (string):

```python
def capital(text, indexes):
  return ''.join(c.upper() if i in indexes else c for i,c in enumerate(text))
```

This would also work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It doens't seem correct to iterate over each character of the string. A more correct approach would be to iterate on each index in `ind` and capitalize those characters.

Anyway this can be one with a one-liner using a list comprehension:

```
def capital(s, ind):
  capitalized = [s[i].upper() if i in ind else s[i] for i in range(len(s))]
  return ''.join(capitalized)
```

Comment: By doing `range(len(s))` you are also iterating over the entire length of the string... So either way this code will perform the same way as the others...

Comment: Or `[s.upper() if i in ind else s for i, s in enumerate(s)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected way to define a function that takes in a list of characters and a list of indexes, and prints out the list with the specified indexes uppercased:

```
test = 'hello there'
l = list(test)

def capital(s, ind):
    for i in ind:
        s[i] = s[i].upper()
    print(s)
    
capital(l,[1,2,5])
```

Output:

```
['h', 'E', 'L', 'l', 'o', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e']
```

---

---

Here is a simpler version that does not require a pre-conversion from a string to a list, it simply takes in a string and a list of indices:

```
def capital(s, ind):
    s = ''.join([c.upper() if i in ind else c for i,c in enumerate(s)])
    print(s)

capital('hello world',[1,2,5])
```

Output:

```
hELlo world
```

Answer (score 0):

see fixes in line. you meant to do this this is the right way to to do it.
in your code `i[ind] = i[ind].upper()`. ind is a list! this is an error. see my code below:

```
test = 'hello there'
l = list(test)

def capital(s, ind):
    for i in range(len(s)):   #i is one letter - charachter 
        if i in ind:
            s[i] = s[i].upper()   #it expects an integer! you have passed a list 
    print(s)
    
capital(l, [1,2,5])
```

**Effictive approach**

```
test = 'hello there'
l = list(test)

def capital(s, ind):
    for i in ind:   #i is one letter - charachter 
        s[i] = s[i].upper()   #it expects an integer! you have passed a list 
    print(s)
    
capital(l, [1,2,5])
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just iterate over the second parameter given to the function and just replacing the needed indexes instead of iterating over the whole string ?

Comment: sure. i will post second approach. bu i want to be close to his logic  and code as i can to show OPs where is he made mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up the list you pass as a second parameter in your `capital` function and the list of caracters you have created. 
Here is a way to properly write your function :

```
test = 'hello there'
def capital(s, ind):
    for i in ind:
        s[i] = s[i].upper()
    return(s)
print(capital(list(test),[1,2,5]))
```

Comment: Removed the ```print``` inside the function, thanks !